# Mongoose common code for getting Connection with Connection pooling

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am writing the following code in all the models I have. Is there a way of writing this in a common file and access it around all models.

```
mongoose.connect(credentials.MONGO_DB_CONNECTION_URL);
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

I also want to have a connection pooling set with few connections. For example

```
mongoose.connection(credentials.MONGO_DB_CONNECTION_URL, {poolSize: 10});
```

How can I write this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a module that exports the connection (E6 style)

```
export default mongoConnection = mongoose.connection(
    credentials.MONGO_DB_CONNECTION_URL, {poolSize: 10})
```

And in each module that needs it:

```
import mongoConnection from "./module-name";
...
mongoConnection.model('Comment', schema);
```

Use the imported connection to initialize your schema or whatever else you need to do.

If you aren't using ES6 imports yet then:

```
const mongoConnection = mongoose.connection(
    credentials.MONGO_DB_CONNECTION_URL, {poolSize: 10})

return module.exports = {mongoConnection}
```